# How to remove ubuntu after Wubi installation

Tags: wubi

i installed ubuntu through Wubi. Now I want  to remove ubuntu.

please help by step by step instructions.

Thanks

Comment: You downloaded wubi or through cd?

Answer (score 0):

If you have downloaded wubi:

1. go to windows
2. and then open downloads folder
3. then open wubi (if you still have it)
4. then click on uninstall.

If you have deleted wubi, you might need to download it again.